# "A remarkable Moufang loop"

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, ho.history-overview

The 1985 paper *[A simple construction of the Fischer-Griess monster group](https://eudml.org/doc/143210)* by Conway refers to an "in press" article, *A remarkable Moufang loop, with an application to the Fischer group $Fi_{24}$*, by Conway and Parker, and also gives a date of 1985. This paper never appeared, as far as I can tell. Worse, the 1988 book *Sphere packings, lattices and groups* lists it as "in preparation", which is going backwards! I know that there was a fair bit of relying on (paper!) preprints in the finite simple group theory community around that time, but I was wondering if this is in any way available today?

Comment: This is certainly NOT an area where I would claim any expertise.  On a whim, I did a general google search for "remarkable Moufang loop" and quickly found a 1995 _[paper](http://www.math.sjsu.edu/~hsu/pdf/tp.pdf)_ by Tim Hsu with a discussion, mention of code loops, references to works of Griess and acknowledgements to Griess and other relevant mathematicians.  You quite possible are already aware of this work and chose not to mention it.  If you haven't already seen this you may want to look at it.

Comment: It might be useful to contact the people closest to this line of research if you haven't already tried that:  John Conway, Richard Parker, Bob Griess.   (By the way, people did have to rely on paper preprints and the postal services at that time.)

Comment: R.Griess published a paper "Codes, loops, and $p$-locals", as a part of 
Groups, Difference Sets, and the Monster: Proceedings of a Special Research Quarter at The Ohio State University, Spring 1993, that  has some info on this. It appears that the unfinished by Conway and Parker job  could have been done by Griess himself.

Comment: @DavidA.Jackson correct: Griess and Hsu have written some nice stuff about code loops, but I really am after the original paper. Wilson, in his book _The finite simple groups_ has a chapter on Fischer groups and introduces the Parker loop briefly, but I want to know what Conway and Parker wrote about it.

Comment: @JimHumphreys I tried emailing Conway just now and his official email address is inactive, due to high volume of mail, presumably a lot of cranky emails. I passed a message onto the Princeton maths department for him in the hope he'll get it.

Comment: @Dima thanks for the reference. I've done a bit more digging around, and at least have a better idea of the general state of the literature on code loops. But still, a paper from Conway on it...

Comment: Well, now I'll never know.